# Vertical alignment with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm starting up a new project, and I've always had an issue getting vertical alignment right in CSS. Is there anything I could do better that what I've currently come up with? Replacing the `header` and `nav` with divs, and changing the `rgba` values to hex values this seems to work all the way back to IE7 which I'm happy with.

**CSS**

```css
html, * {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

nav a.tab {
    text-align:center;
    padding:0 15px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:inline-table;

    vertical-align:middle;  text-decoration:none;
}

nav a.tab > span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

nav a.tab:hover {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-decoration:underline;
}

header {
    background-color:#27AE60;
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#FFF;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

header, header h1, header nav, header nav a.tab {
    height:80px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

header nav {
    display:inline-block;
}

header h1 {
    margin:0 20px;
    display:inline;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #333333;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<header>
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <nav>
        <a href="/" class="tab active">
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/projects" class="tab">
            <span>Projects</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/" class="tab">
            <span>Contact</span>
        </a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2pz728d/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good - both the CSS and the HTML validate at the validators:

> [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)
>   [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input)

However, you should put your wrap your HTML code like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Page title here...</title>
        <!-- other links here, such as external CSS/JS files -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- your code here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

I really like how you use the HTML5 `header` element instead of using the old style `<div class="header">`

When people write CSS, they often format it slightly different, like this:

```css
nav a.tab > span {
    display:        table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It is just easier to read this way.  Also, you should have each element have its own line, not put many on the same line like this:

```css
vertical-align:middle;  text-decoration:none;
```

Otherwise, this looks good to me.

Comment: It actually is inside all the html tags etc, I just posted the relevant part to the question :), and also those rule we're suppose to be on separate lines, I just messed up the copy paste haha :P. I haven't actually seen CSS wrote with the spaces like that, but it is a whole lot easier to read, so I'm gonna change it all over now. Thanks for your tips :)

Comment: Glad to help.  Yes, I thought this might just be the relevant part, but I have seen so much bad HTML that displays different in every browser out there that I always put this in my answers.

Answer (score 3):

I only have some nitpicks about formatting and readability.
Hopefully somebody else will comment specifically about good approaches for treating vertical alignment.

It would be more readable (and the common convention) to put a space after colons.
So instead of:

> ```
> background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
> text-decoration:underline;
> ```

Write as:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
text-decoration: underline;
```

And don't put two definitions on the same line like this:

> ```
> vertical-align:middle;  text-decoration:none;
> ```

It's better when code reads from top to bottom,
and your eyes can stay focusing on the left,
rather than dipping deeper into the right part, like this:

```
vertical-align: middle;
text-decoration: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's one more way to center vertically

```
element { 
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: If you're hoping to support IE8 or older, this method will be outright broken because the transform property is only supported in IE9+ (note that the OP specifically mentions that IE7 support is a "good thing").

Comment: yes, that's right